# How to use Pentaho Community API

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I have a pentaho community server 8.1 already running and i would like to know if this version has a API avaliable? Im using the following code to and getting a 200 but there is no basic so i can authenticate correctly.

```
import requests

data = {"j_username": "admin","j_password":"password"}
r = requests.post('http://(serverip):8080/pentaho/j_spring_security_check', data = data)
```

Is the authentication for this api configurable?

The whole idea is that i can use the scheduler since the spoon for the community version doest has access to it BUT i tried using the enterprice client and i was able to schedule so the module is there you just cant reach it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and the full API is documented here:

https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.1/Developer_Center/REST_API

Note: If you want to enable username/password authentication on the URL you have to edit security.properties and reboot . (an older insecure approach, but for the purposes of development possibly simpler to get you going)

You're absolutely right - the CORE platform does have the functionality, just not the UI so you're more than welcome to use the API to use the scheduler engine.